# iOS7 text size of navigation bar button

Tags: uinavigationbar, font-size, ios7

I converted app to **iOS7** by **Xcode5 GM**.

And I noticed button's UI none-border also increasing font size for `navigation bar button`.
My question is, why increase `font size` of `navigation bar button` on ios7?
There has a rule something?